# Loops full JsonObject using Google Gson recursively

Tags: java, json, gson

I want loops across the full object, with **all their properties** recursively, I am using google **gson** for first time, and I can't get all the properties values (how String)

Any can help me with this?

A example of **JSON**:

```
{"data1":100,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"]}
```

I really don't know the real format of the **JSON**, but I know that if can have a lot of sons properties and list, Its really important get all values (repeateds keys or not)

I tried with the `toString()` with full object at First but I can't get only the values (I tried using `entrySet`, converting to `JSONArray`... but Im becoming crazy)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with finally with this code:

Sometimes is better rest a little :)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : json.entrySet()) {

        if (entry.getValue().isJsonObject()) {
            sb.append(getJsonTokenize(entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject()));
        } else {
            sb.append(entry.getValue().getAsString());
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: getJsonTokenize() is the name of this recursive function? What if a entry.value is an array that contains again JsonObjects and not only primitive values? Don't you want to collect their values too?